# gitlab Health Check is Unhealthy

Tags: mysql, ruby, postgresql, gitlab

I'm migration my gitlab to another server. the old gitlab server use postgresql and the new gitlab server use mysql.

I'm convert it with tools calld “DBConvert for MySQL & PostgreSQL”.
Database had sucess convert , and the repo files also copyd to the new gitlab server.
But my projects can't use , when click the projects it notice http code 500.

In gitlab Health check ,it notice

```
Migrations are pending.  
To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production"
```

And when I run this cmd , it notice "No Rakefile found"

How to proceed from there?

Comment: @VonC Thank for your answer,I'm install gitlab from source,and under the gitlab install path,execute both of `bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` and `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`,i'm got the same output:`Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'real_size':`

Comment: From which version of GitLab are you migrating? See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/23881

Comment: Hi VonC my src and dst gitlab version are 8.8.4 , it's the same.On the page which you giev me , i found the `Status Migration ID Migration Name` : `up 20160204144558 Add real size to merge request diffs`.It's the same which when i run cmd in my system,i got the output: `== 20160204144558 AddRealSizeToMergeRequestDiffs: migrating ==`. Is this information can help me ?

Comment: I have edited my answer

Comment: Although I didn't quite understand, but thank you all the same!

Comment: I you migrate from 8.8.4 to 8.8.4, no need to do any database migration: do not execute `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: @VonC Thanks a lot~ Now my problem is resolved.The problem is the version of table schema_migrations , i select version from Postpresql, the result is:`20160204144558`,and i select verison from MySQL , the result is :`181-TRIAL-20160204144558 27`, after i updated it , it's OK~ see [link](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/24997#note_19042906)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resloved , see link [How to resloved `"Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production".`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/24997#note_19042906)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to execute [`bin/rake`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/7c9909eb64ce346fc40a831493ffe8faef3d9d9d/bin/rake) `db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` from your GitLab-CE installation folder.

Or try from the same GitLab folder:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production"
```

> my src and dst gitlab version are 8.8.4 , it's the same

In that case, simply do *not* execute any  `db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`: that will avoid creating duplicate tables.